# How to remove product from cart

Tags: javascript, html, json, shopping-cart

I have a question about javascript. I have a cart and a function which removes a product from that cart. How can I do a redirect to the main page when the cart is empty?

This is my function delete product.

```
function removeCart(key) {
$.ajax({
    url: 'index.php?route=checkout/cart/update',
    type: 'post',
    data: 'remove=' + key,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(json) {
        $('.success, .warning, .attention, .information').remove();

        if (json['output']) {
            $('#cart_total').html(json['total']);
            $("table.total tr:last td:last").text(json['total'].split('-')[1]);

            $('#cart .content').html(json['output']);
        }           
    }
});
}
```

Comment: I know it, but when i must to do this? How i know this when cart is empty

Comment: @Stars just check if there is no products.

Comment: The removing of products doesn't seem to be the issue here, only checking when your cart is empty. To help you with that we need to know how you build your cart.

Comment: what does total store? if thats the count or total value, ypu can check if that zero & then redirect

Comment: @Stars As this is your software, how should anyone know how to check whether the cart is empty. Or are you using a known shop-software? If yes, you should name it.

Comment: It's OpenCart, and build cart default like OpenCart must to do. add to cart, remove, edit with ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get your cart when you do the update. If the cart is empty you can return that in your ajax response. For example by setting an emptyCart key in your array:

```
function removeCart(key) {
$.ajax({
    url: 'index.php?route=checkout/cart/update',
    type: 'post',
    data: 'remove=' + key,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(json) {
        $('.success, .warning, .attention, .information').remove();
        if (json['emptyCart']) {
            location.href="/where-you-want-it-to-go";
        }
        if (json['output']) {
            $('#cart_total').html(json['total']);
            $("table.total tr:last td:last").text(json['total'].split('-')[1]);

            $('#cart .content').html(json['output']);
        }
    }
});
}
```